# Which a design pattern i should use for set athletic places in competition by points?

Tags: java, design-patterns, software-design

I have a class `AthleticCompetitionResults` and want to create a class with method to return a object of this `AthleticCompetitionResults` initialized from lines e.g.

> Siim Susi;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72
>
> Siim Susi2;12.61;5.00;9.22;1.50;60.39;16.43;21.60;2.60;35.81;5.25.72
>
> Jaana Lind;13.75;4.84;10.12;1.50;68.44;19.18;30.85;2.80;33.88;6.22.75

```
public class AthleticCompetitionResults {
  private Athletic athletic;
  private float resultM100;
  private float resultLongJump;
  private float resultShotPut;
  private float resultHighJump;
  private float resultM400;
  private float resultHurdles110m;
  private float resultDiscusThrow;
  private float resultPoleVault;
  private float resultJavelinThrow;
  private float resultM1500;
  private int points;


public AthleticCompetitionResults(Athletic athletic) {
    this.athletic = athletic;
}

public void countPoints(){
   //counting
}

// setters and getters
...
```

**EDITED:** 
My goal is to print list of `List<AthleticCompetitionResults>` ordering by points and print of place in competition. If points is equals than print `1-2` place. Example:

> 1-2 Siim Susi   4200 pts 
> 1-2 Siim Susi2  4200 pts 
> 3 Jaana Lind  3494 pts

What best way to save places of Athletic competition? What about `List<Integer>' places in class 'AthleticCompetitionResults`?

```
public class Competition{
  private List<AthleticCompetitionResults> athleticsData;
  
  public Competition(List<AthleticCompetitionResults> data){
     this.athleticsData = data;
  }

  public void sortByPoints(){
   //sorting by points
  }

  public void setPlaces(){
    //setting athletics places in competition by points
  }

  public void print(){
     //printing e.g 1-2 Siim Susi 4200 pts ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have bigger design issues rather than worrying about patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering :

**Not all events result in time**

- e.g wrestling, shooting)

**Results depends on kind of events**

- sprints have finishing time and ranks
- wrestling has winner/looser

**Result attributes are similar for some group of events**

- 100m sprint, 500m sprint, swimming, marathon have finishing times.
- javelin, shotput, discuss throws have distance.
- all events have a clear winner

We need a **STRATEGY**  so that depending on event type, our result attributes can change.

Lets try to put down some sample code for it:

```
class Result {
  protected boolean winner;
  ..
};

class ThrowingResult extends Result{
  protected float range;
  ..
}

class SprintResult extends Result{
  protected double timeToFinishInMilliseconds;
  protected int finalPosition;
  ..
}

class AthleticCompetitionResults{
  private Athletic athletic;

  private SprintResult resultM100;
  private SprintResult resultLongJump;

  private ThrowingResult javelin;
  private ThrowingResult shotPut;

  private Result wrestling;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to keep this data inside a `Map`.

The keys will be written inside this class as `final`.

**Like this:**

```
private Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

public static final String ATHLETIC_NAME = "Athletic_Name";
public static final String FIELD_1 = "Field_1";
public static final String FIELD_2 = "Field_2";
public static final String FIELD_3 = "Field_3";
public static final String FIELD_4 = "Field_4";
public static final String FIELD_5 = "Field_5";

private static final String[] FIELDS_LIST = new String[]{
    ATHLETIC_NAME,
    FIELD_1,
    FIELD_2,
    FIELD_3,
    FIELD_4,
    FIELD_5
};


private void getParametersMap(String values){

    System.out.println("Loaded Parameters:");

    try{ 
        String[] splitted = values.split(";");

        if (splitted.length != FIELDS_LIST.length){
            throw new Exception("Unmatched arrays size!!");
        }
        int i=0;
        for (String keyItem : FIELDS_LIST){     
            valuesMap.put(keyItem, splitted[i++]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would even go for `enum` type. But yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your only constructor used in this class then changing it to builder/factory will not make any significant difference. I'd stay with constructor in this case. Covering it with fancy pattern name won't make it much better.